# Symfony2 / Doctrine: one to one, embedded entity

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm starting the serious play with doctrine.

Among my current challenges, I have to build an entity which contains an address. Let's take an example.

```
class Address {
    private $country;
    private $street;
}

class Person {
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var Address
     */
    private $address;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to have only one table in database, with Address being embedded in  Person. Something of the like:

```
create table Person {
     name string(255),
     street string(255),
     country string(255)
}
```

I know this is possible with ORMs like Hibernate, and I wish I could have the same behaviour with Doctrine.

**How can I have an embedded one-to-one relationship with Doctrine ?**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Doctrine's ORM doesn't support embedded objects. The only soultion I found so far is to do the mapping on your own:

```
class Person {
    ...

    protected $addressName;
    protected $addressStreet;
    protected $addressCountry;

    public function getAddress() {
        return new Address($this->addressName, $this->addressStreet, $this->addressCountry);

        // or Address::create(...) if you wan't to have a simple constructor
    }

    public function setAddress(Address $address) {
        $this->addressName = $address->getName();
        $this->addressStreet = $address->getStreet();
        $this->addressCountry = $address->getCountry();
    }

    ...
}
```

It's quite a lot of repeated code, so you can think about moving it into separate [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Comment: Doctrine does support embedded objects: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html

Comment: @PavelGalaton: Yes, they have finally added support for that!